# How to run "sudo su tomcat" from a .NET application

Tags: .net, tomcat, ssh, sudo, winscp-net

I need to run shell scripts (shutdown scripts for tomcat) with the tomcat user out from a C# .NET application.

I tried with the WinSCP .NET assembly. I can login via `ssh` and run commands.

But how to run `sudo su tomcat` first with the same password I already used to login the SSH server?

A secure solution would be great (no passwords in log files or bash history)!

Maybe any other solution instead of WinSCP .NET assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo`/`su` are made not to be automatable. For a good reason.

So any solution will be a dirty and unreliable hack.

If you need to be able to allow an automatic run of some command, allow it to be run without a password in `sudoers`. That's the correct and transparent solution.